# PL/SQL calling a function inside a trigger

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, triggers

I am trying to create a function using Oracle PL/SQL that stores the current date into a variable. This function will be called inside a trigger. The trigger (among other things) will insert this variable into a new table that has already been created. My code complies and runs without errors, but it doesn't work. Nothing happens. The trigger is an ON DELETE trigger, so when I delete one row from the original table, it just stays. Any clues what I am missing? Thank you.

Function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_date (i_stdid archive_student.stdid%TYPE)
    RETURN date
    AS
       v_date DATE;
    BEGIN
       SELECT CURRENT_DATE INTO v_date FROM DUAL; 
    RETURN v_date;
    END;
```

Function call inside trigger:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ARCHIVE_DELETED_STUDENT
    AFTER DELETE ON STUDENT
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE 
        v_date archive_student.change_date%TYPE;
    BEGIN
        -- other if statements here that are working properly
        v_date := get_date(:old.stdid);
        INSERT INTO archive_student (change_date) VALUES (v_date);
    END;
```

Comment: Add `commit` after your insert statement

Comment: @Polppan, using `commit, rollback, set transaction and savepoint` is not allowed in triggers, if you try you get ORA-04092 error.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you have posted which would prevent a row from being deleted.  So clearly the problem lies in some part of the code you have redacted.

Comment: @kordirko Yes you are absolutely right, commit in trigger would raise `ORA-04092`

Comment: Are there other columns in the ARCHIVE_STUDENT table which should be filled in?  You're inserting a row with the CHANGE_DATE populated but not any other fields.  ???

Comment: Yes, my IF statement populated the other columns. I should have included that too, but I felt it was too much code. The solution ThinkJet offered below worked. I was leaving out the stdid which cannot be null in the INSERT INTO statement. Once I added that, it worked. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You doing well, check [this SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52e57/10).

Only one thing - you missed `stdid` while inserting into `archive_student` so it is null after insert.